# How to reduce search time on a DropDownList's AutoCorrect/Suggest databound to List<T>

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

This is using Telerik controls for WinForms, VS 2017 RC, and .Net 4.6.x.

I've been tasked with bringing a .Net 1.1 app up to modern day.   One of the requirements is to minimize the learning curve (i.e. don't change the UI much) for the staff that uses the app.  This means replacing a WinForms `Combobox` with a `RadDropDownList` and enabling Autocomplete; Unfortunately, one of the "DDL"s is bound to >200,000 records.  Specifically, these are Account names and numbers.

The problem arises when typing into the text element. Common characters cause the program to slam the brakes while the list of matches updates (God forbid someone type a "2"), giving a very "Prodigy Chat in the 90's" level of performance that just won't fly.  I've tried a few approaches, the most recent being this:

```
 public static Dictionary<Control, DateTime> ControlUpdateList 
                  = new Dictionary<Control, DateTime>();
 public static void UpdateMode(RadDropDownList rddl, int countOfChars)
        {
            if (ControlUpdateList.Keys.Contains(rddl))
            {
                TimeSpan s = DateTime.Now - ControlUpdateList[rddl];
                if (s.Seconds < 1.0)
                {
                    //abort if the person is probably still typing. 
                    ControlUpdateList[rddl] = DateTime.Now;
                    return;
                }

                if (rddl.Text.Length >= countOfChars)
                {
                    if (rddl.AutoCompleteMode != AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend)
                        rddl.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;


                }
                else
                {
                    if (rddl.AutoCompleteMode != AutoCompleteMode.None)    
                     rddl.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
                }


                 ControlUpdateList[rddl] = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                ControlUpdateList.Add(rddl, DateTime.Now);
            }

        }
```

The idea being that we simply don't turn Autocomplete on until the user has finished typing a `string`. This helped, as the user has no idea that the lag occurred.  Unfortunately, they'll find out as soon as they type another character, and we have too many users who finger-peck the keyboard to make this feasible.

Other ideas I've tried include: Databinding after x characters are typed (nope), trying just the `Append` or `Suggest` Autocomplete options (nope), trimming unused records from the datasource (there are none), nullifying the `.Value` of everything in the `ddl.Items` list (super-slight improvement), replacing it with a textbox and a query button (rejected as negatively impacting workflow compared to current application).

My first instinct is to just swap back to WinForms controls, since the Telerik controls are much more "heavyweight" than WinForms, which just wraps a native combobox. Unfortunately, that falls outside of project requirements.  I'm fresh out of ideas, and I know it's an open-ended question, but where can I go from here to improve the performance of this control?  The current delay is still nearly 2 seconds between keypresses.  Also, the datasource is a `List<T>` of `Account` objects and the `Text` value of each `Item` is established with an overridden `ToString()` method in the object.

Comment: Is the autocomplete pulling all of the matching data from the db on every keypress? Can you try a "top 10" instead of all the records that match? Also, is it possible to server-side cache the 200,000 records?

Comment: The Autocomplete here is a function of the Telerik control.  I can tell it to check by "StartsWith" instead of "Contains", but that's it.  The 200,000+ records are actually loaded when the program loads and kept globally available to the application, so the delay is not being caused by calls to the server.  That was the very first thing I changed when trying to sort this out.

Comment: Unfortunately, other than lobbying to change your technology requirements, I don't really have any suggestions. It's been my personal experience that Telerik controls do more for unifying a UI and adding features than simplifying development or improving performance.

Comment: Yeah it's slow. But why 200,000 records in a drop down list ? You expect user to scroll down to `Item 95862`. A drop down is information that need or can be scrolled. If it's something commonly used then it should not have delay. Use i dont know 2 text box and a "Search popup". Design it an other way.

Comment: I you are a paid user, try to post a support ticket, I think they can come up with something.

Comment: @Pierre Lebon ; part of what I'm dealing with is design constraints imposed on the project.  The DropDownList begins with a numeric value that can be between 2 and 6 digits, followed by the account name.  Part of the reason for the "DDL" is because the WinForms version of the control from .Net 1.1 is what is used on the current version, and unfortunately they want the same basic control.  SO short answer, yes, the users *already* scroll down if typing the number (which they usually know off the top of their head) or the first few name characters doesn't find the record.

Comment: How does the old `DDL` behave ? Laggy also ?

Comment: Yes, but less so because it's a WInForms native control instead of a Telerik managed one.  They still expect a performance improvement, which makes me think I've got to divide the List<T> up somehow.

Comment: @user1895086, As it won't fit as an answer and it's to big for a comment I'll describe in few word how I handled something like this.
2 text box + 1 search button. 1 text box they can type the ID on text change if there is only one result possible the name is displayed in the 2nd text box that is disable. If they don't know numbers the button is a "pop up form" with a top 10 grid and field for quick research. Double click on a result fill the information in the previous form.

Comment: But it's quite a big change. but you can try to sell it that way if it has better performance and display more field they can research a customer. This way my User can even sneak pick into other customer information with the grid. As the button take the input of the 1rst text box as entry search.